# How to setup a Log4j2 JDBC Appender in a YAML configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

Since the Log4j2 documentation unfortunately doesn't have any examples for specifying a JDBC Appender using a ConnectionFactory in a log4j2.yaml-configuration, i'd like to ask for a proper example.

This is my current state of the log4j2.yml:

```yaml
Configuration:
  //...

  Appenders:

    JDBC:
      name: DataBase
      connectionSource:
        class: "com.example.config.Log4jConnectionFactory"
        method: "getDbConnection"

      tableName: "application_log"
      columnConfigs:
        - name: "log_date"
          isEventTimestamp: true
        - name: "log_level"
          pattern: "%level"
        - name: "logger"
          pattern: "%logger"
        - name: "user_id"
          pattern: "$${ctx:userId}"
        - name: "user_name"
          pattern: "$${ctx:username}"
        - name: "log_message"
          pattern: "%message"
        - name: "exception"
          pattern: "%exception"

  //...
```

And here the associated ConnectionFactory:

```java
public class Log4jConnectionFactory {

    private static BasicDataSource dataSource;

    private Log4jConnectionFactory() { }

    public static Connection getDbConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:example-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("");
        }

        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

With this configuration above Log4j throws the following error:

```
No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender
```

The complete error log:

```
2023-02-03 09:38:08,479 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for connectionSource
2023-02-03 09:38:08,481 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,481 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,481 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,482 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,482 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,482 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,482 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,566 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for connectionSource
2023-02-03 09:38:08,566 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,566 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,567 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,567 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,567 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,567 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,567 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for columnConfigs
2023-02-03 09:38:08,569 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender for element JDBC: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginType.getElementName()" because "childType" is null java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginType.getElementName()" because "childType" is null
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:104)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:88)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:664)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:391)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:416)
    at com.example.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:13)

2023-02-03 09:38:08,571 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender for element JDBC: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:664)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:391)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:416)
    at com.example.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:13)
```

Since I'm not sure whether the Appender structure is correct or not, and since I haven't found anything anywhere how this shoud be done in a YAML config file, and since the Log4j2 documentation isn't any help either, I'd like to ask for any help that can provide some clarification.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since this didn't leave me any peace, I invested a few extra hours and tried out many possible combinations and setups. In the end I came up with the following proper working solution:

log4j2.yaml:

```yaml
Configuration:
  //...

  Appenders:

    JDBC:
      name: DataBase
      ConnectionFactory:
        class: "com.example.config.Log4jConnectionFactory"
        method: "getDbConnection"

      tableName: "application_log"
      Column:
        - name: "log_date"
          isEventTimestamp: true
        - name: "log_level"
          pattern: "%level"
        - name: "logger"
          pattern: "%logger"
        - name: "user_id"
          pattern: "$${ctx:userId}"
        - name: "user_name"
          pattern: "$${ctx:username}"
        - name: "log_message"
          pattern: "%message"
        - name: "exception"
          pattern: "%exception"

  //...
```

ConnectionFactory:

```java
public class Log4jConnectionFactory {

    private static final HikariDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        System.out.println("====================== This is Log4jConnectionFactory speaking ======================");

        dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:example-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './src/db/h2/schema-log4j2.sql'");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
    }

    private Log4jConnectionFactory() { }

    public static Connection getDbConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

schema-log4j2.sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application_log` (
    application_log_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    log_date           TIMESTAMP,
    log_level          VARCHAR(10),
    logger             VARCHAR(100),
    user_id            BIGINT,
    user_name          VARCHAR(50),
    log_message        TEXT,
    exception          TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY (application_log_id)
);
```

Since we are in a Spring Boot environment and an H2 database is used, we have to consider that both logger and database have to be ready for use at a point, where Spring Boot itself is still in the initialization phase. Therefore logger and database must be setup without the help of Spring Boot, respectively without the application.yml configuration file.

So since schema creation can't be done via config file, we assign this task to the H2-connection-string. However, this means that every time a connection is requested, the schema creation is processed. To not run into an error see the detail `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Also to be mentioned, the connection data is currently hardcoded. This is definitely not a great solution, and I'm still looking for a way to work around this. A lookup to the Spring context is not possible due to timing reasons already mentioned. JNDI doesn't make much sense either, since the Tomcat configuration for this happens also too late. Let's see what solution eventually it will be. If I'll find one, I will update this post.

Comment: Spring Boot reconfigures Log4j2 as soon as the `Environment` is available. You can start with a file/console appender in `log4j2.yaml` and add the JDBC appender in `log4j2-spring.yaml`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz That sounds interesting. Could you maybe explain it a little bit more? I tried to take the appender and its assignment out of log4j2.yml and put it into log4j2-spring.yml, hoping that Spring Boot's magic would somehow do some kind of merging and reconfiguration. Doesn't seem to be enough though. What other settings do I need to do? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Spring Boot does not merge, it just replaces one config file with the second one. You can also stick to a single file and use a `SpringProfile` arbiter (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot/index.html)): at startup any definition in the arbiter will be ignored (no environment) and it will be used only after an `Environment` is present.

Comment: Placing the `log4j2.yml` allone seems not to be enough. I had to set the `logging.config: "classpath:log4j2-spring.yml"` property as well to make Spring Boot recognizing the second config file. Unfortunately, there still seems to be a little hickup during the init-process. I test-wise added the DataBase appender to the Root logger, and the first console log line is `2023-02-04 09:19:22,751 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "Database" for logger config "root"`. I know that Bootstrapping is no simple thing, but somehow this gives an odd feeling.

Comment: Having two almost redundant complex config files is another thing :/. However, I am very grateful for this info and will now take a closer look at the arbiter. Let's see what will ultimately make me happy :)